# Increase images size using linear resampling via shell

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

How I can convert an entire image folder of pixel art images to double size without blur pixels ? I try with mogrify but blurs the inside of images. ( border works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to preserve pixels without blurring, you would use `-scale` or `-sample`. There are great examples and detailed explanations in the [usage documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#sample).

```sh
mogrify pixels/*.png -scale 100x100 -path ./scale
```

[image: pixel]
[image: scale]

```sh
mogrify pixels/*.png -sample 100x100 -path ./sample
```

[image: pixel]
[image: sample]

Comment: I was searching the -sample option, thanks you.   With -filter point on -scale for obtain same result than sample but it's more slow